# Renderize latex in octave-kernel for jupyeter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, octave

I would like to renderize `latex` in `jupyter notebook` with `octave-kernel`

In octave with the `symbolic` package I'm able to print `latex` strings via `latex()` function, in jupyter, like:

```
>> latex(sym(eye(3)))
\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]
```

Is there a way to renderize this latex string in jupyter notebook?

Comment: It depends what you mean; the question has a very broad scope for interpretation. The `display` function is supported in octave too, so if what you want is an ascii/utf8 representation of that object, you can just do `display( sym( eye( 3 ) ) )`. If instead you want _actual_ latex markup, you can just run `latex(...` and copy paste the markup into a cell, and use one of the many methods (unrelated to octave) for displaying latex on jupyter notebooks.

Comment: also, if you're not after a _jupyter_ notebook specifically, but just a nice way to create reports, note that octave has a very nice `publish` function which creates nice reports directly from normal octave scripts, and supports simple syntax for including latex markup.

Comment: I mean that I would like like actual latex markup, probably I made a mistake citing display for a misunderstanding

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would do it in python?